# Why does python3 timeit setup improve the time so dramatically?

Tags: python-3.x

In the examples below, why does the line without the setup take so much longer?

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit( setup = "M=range(100);f=lambda x: x*2", stmt = "[f(m) for m in M]"))
print(timeit.timeit( stmt = "[(lambda x:x*2)(m) for m in range(100)]"))

17.038363554
26.128148989000003
```

Comment: I put the two list comprehensions in separate python files, and executed them with `time` command. The second one still is about 20-25% slower. So this doesn't have to do with `timeit`. I suspect the reason being that in the second version the lambda is being redefined every time it loops over.

Comment: Doing more takes more time. What did you expect?

Comment: @KellyBundy  let me explain, the lambda function and the range are exactly the same for both lines. The only difference is that in the first line the lambda function and the range are initialized via the setup argument. All I want to know is why the setup makes such a big difference in this case.

Comment: The functions are the same *once they're created*. But as @jingx already said, your second version creates it over and over again. Maybe [disassemble](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCEls5gLiPWAWEM9WiMnMTcpJVGhwqpCy0hTI1dTIS2/SCFXITNPoSgxLz1Vw9DAQDNWXfP/fwA) both if you want to see the differences?